# Decarga PDF con Selenium en Eclipse - Chrome

Tags: eclipse, pdf, selenium, descarga

Estoy necesitando descargar un archivo PDF en Chrome, para luego poder comparar información que este contiene en su interior.
El problema es que no me está descargando.
La descarga la realizo desde el botón descargar de Chrome(LA FLECHITA), pero no me la genera.
El código cuando lo corro, y el clic sobre la flechita lo realizo manual, se descarga automatico, mientras que cuando lo dejo correr hasta el final sin hacer el clic manual se rompe y no me descarga el PDF.
Este código lo arme porque no podía interactuar con la pantalla de guardar Como.
Probé con el sendKeys.... para ver si funcionaba el CTRL + s pero no me lo tomó.

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comparto parte del código para saber si hay alguna falencia.
Desde ya, agradezco como siempre las respuestas y la ayuda.

package com.qualitystream.testng;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestNG {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String downloadFilePath = "C:\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\xxx\\xxxxxx\\xxxxxx\\DescargaPDF";
    By usernameLocator = By.id("vUSERNAME");
    By passwordLocator = By.id("vUSERPASSWORD");
    By registerBtnLocator = By.name("LOGIN");
    By menuBtnLocator = By.cssSelector("input[name='BTNTOGGLEMENU_MPAGE']");
    By xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx = By.xpath("//span[@class='sidebar-nav-item'][contains(.,'pp')]");
    By emisionDeuda = By.xpath("(//a[contains(.,'pp')])[1]");
    By atencionPrimaria = By.xpath("(//a[contains(.,'pp')])[1]");
    By filtroObjeto = By.name("vFILTROGENERAL");`introducir el código aquí`
    By buscarBtn = By.id("BUSCAR");
    By consultarBtn = By.xpath("(//a[@class='ui right floated big purple label'][contains(.,'Consultar')])[1]");
    By tasasObjetos = By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'TABSCONTROLContainerpanel1')][@href='#Tab_TabControl'][contains(.,'TASAS/SERVICIOS/OBJETOS')]");
    By checkObligaciones = By.xpath("//label[@for='vCHECKALL_GRIDOBLIGACIONES'][contains(.,'_')]");
    

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/chromedriver/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe");

        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilePath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    @Test
    public void Descarga() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(registerBtnLocator).click();
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        driver.findElement(menuBtnLocator).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(tributariofaroBtnLocator).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(emisionDeuda).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(atencionPrimaria).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.findElement(filtroObjeto).sendKeys("46860");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(buscarBtn).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(consultarBtn).click();
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        driver.findElement(tasasObjetos).click();
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        driver.findElement(checkObligaciones).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        WebElement imprimirBtnContado = driver.findElement(By.id("IMPRIMIRCONTADO"));
        imprimirBtnContado.click();
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        WebElement downloadButton = driver.findElement(By.id("download"));
        downloadButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Verificar la descarga de archivos
        File folder = new File(downloadFilePath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        assertTrue(listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0, "No se descargaron archivos correctamente");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBeRw.png
```